# C Numbers Guessing Game

Tags: c

Im just starting to learn C programming and for exercise i found this task. It's a number guessing game where computer guesses the number that i have in mind. First i have to think of a number. Then i have to scan in the range in which the number is. Then computer generates a number in that range and asks me it is correct. Based on computers answer i have to reply with L if its too low, H if it is too high and G if it is correct. If it is correct it prints it out and the number of attempts as well. If any other character is entered it prints out that i have entered the wrong answer.

This is what i've got so far. It doesn't give me any errors but when i enter either L, H or G it prints out that i entered the wrong answer.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


void main(){

    int randomNo = 0;
    int input = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    int min = 0;
    int max = 0;
    char answer = ' ';
    char low = 'L';
    char high = 'H';
    char good = 'G';


    printf("Enter min and max: ");
    scanf_s("%d %d", &min, &max);       

    do{     
        randomNo = min + rand() % (max - min) + 1;
        printf("Is it %d?\n", randomNo);
        printf("Enter your answer:");
        scanf_s("%s", &answer);

        if (answer == low){
            printf("Number guessed is low\n");
            min = randomNo;
            counter++;
        }
        else if (answer == high){
            printf("Number guessed is high\n");
            max = randomNo;
            counter++;
        }
        else{
            printf("You entered the wrong answer!\nYour answer should be L - too low H - too high G - goed\n");
        }
    } while (answer != good);

    printf("Your answer is correct!\nYou guessed it in %d times!\n", counter);

}
```

Comment: Your `if` statement needs to handle `answer == good` also, otherwise you'll print `wrong answer` when you enter `G`. You can simply change the last `else` to `else if (answer != good)`.

Comment: `void main()` should be `int main(void)`.

Comment: What's the reason you use `scanf_s` instead of `scanf` (or `fgets`/`getchar` etc)? It's way less portable and has no advantage whatsoever. In case you _have to_ use it (because it is an assignment where you have to or the like): Which version do you use -- the CRT version from Microsoft or the standardized one from C11's Annex K?

Comment: I'm writing the code in Visual Studio 2013 and it doesn't allow the use of scanf because it's unsafe. But i will try fgets and getchar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
scanf_s("%s", &answer);
```

Use:

```
scanf_s(" %c", &answer);
```

As `answer` is not a string,but is a character.

You also need to change `else` to `else if(answer != 'G')` or to `else if(answer != good)`. `rand` will also generate the same value. In order to generate random values, you need

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

At the start of `main`. This is the [pseudo-random number
generator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/)

Answer (score 1):

```
scanf_s("%s", &answer);
```

Should be:

```
scanf_s("%c", &answer); /* answer is a char (not a string) */
```

On the other hand:

> Two different initializations with the same seed will generate the
>   same succession of results in subsequent calls to rand.
>
> If seed is set to 1, the generator is reinitialized to its initial
>   value and produces the same values as before any call to rand or
>   srand.
>
> In order to generate random-like numbers, srand is usually initialized
>   to some distinctive runtime value, like the value returned by function
>   time (declared in header ). This is distinctive enough for most
>   trivial randomization needs.

Add `srand(time(NULL));` at the very begin.

Answer (score 0):

Your `scanf_s` is "scanning" for a string (`%s`), not a `char` (`%c`).

Use `scanf_s("%c", &answer)` ! :)

Comment: why `scanf_s` and not `scanf` ?

Comment: @chouaib, [scanf_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/w40768et.aspx) have security enhancements.

Comment: He's using scanf_s, he probably got his reason (may the tutorial he's following, or may he prefer to use scanf_s all the time). I won't ask him to change that :O

Comment: @AlterMann: `scanf_s` isn't safer than `scanf` (both are dangerous if used wrongly and safe if used correctly) and all the answers given here nicely show why (UB in all cases).

Comment: @Sorikairo: Maybe OP is using MSVC and misled by the warnings against some standard C functions it gives to encourage people writing less portable code.